# slider for event calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm doing a calendar page which contain a slider for the weeks and each day is connected to . the events will appear in the same page.

[you can see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwpgZ.png)

If you have better alternative I will be thankful, because I should deliver this assignment by Wednesday..

Thanks in advance

here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="week-container">
      <ul class="week">
        <li class="day-name" id="active"><span>Mon</span></li>
        <li class="day-name"><span>Tue</span></li>
        <li class="day-name"><span>Wed</span></li>
        <li class="day-name"><span>Thu</span></li>
        <li class="day-name"><span>Fri</span></li>
        <li class="day-name"><span>Sat</span></li>
        <li class="day-name"><span>Sun</span></li>

      </ul>

        <div class="days-arrows"> 
        <a class="prev-day" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a> 
        <a class="next-day" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a> 
        </div>
      <ul class="week">

        <li class="day" id="active"><span>1</span></li>
        <li class="day"><span>2</span></li>
        <li class="day"><span>3</span></li>
        <li class="day"><span>4</span></li>
        <li class="day"><span>5</span></li>
        <li class="day"><span>6</span></li>
        <li class="day"><span>7</span></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
```

here is my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".next-day").click(function () {
    $(".day span").html(function (i, val) {
        return +val + 7;

   });
      });


  $(".prev-day").click(function () {
    $(".day span").html(function (i, val) {
      return +val - 7

    });
    });  
});
```

Comment: [Refer this](http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Beautiful-Multifunctional-Calendar-Plugin-For-jQuery-PIGNOSE-Calender.html)

Comment: remove the inline `onclick` event in html